# Как безопасно проверить правильность расшифровки?

Tags: blowfish, шифрование

Предположим, есть массив в 1 Гб данных. Этот массив был расшифрован симметричным алгоритмом. Перед тем, как использовать те данные, которые в нем содержатся, есть потребность проверить их на осмысленность (то, что это действительно данные, а не беспорядочная каша). Если проверить, например, последний 1 Кб данных, будет ли это надежно и достаточно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А нельзя туда добавлять специальные поля для хэша? CRC32, например?
Он достаточно хорошо различает неидентичные блоки данных.=)

Но вообще, как мне кажется, если ключ верен - то расшифруется корректно весь массив.

Comment: Да, можно добавить хэш.

Comment: Любой хеш, вообще любая проверка части расшифрованного даёт лишь оценку вероятности правильной расшифровки. Устраивает Вас эта вероятность? Обычно разработчики хеш-функций исходят из того, что в таком-то классе задач вероятность достаточна. А входит ли именно Ваша задача в такой класс? Вот над чем надо подумать. И выбрать тот хеш, надёжность которого Вас устроит.

Comment: Кроме того, это ещё и уязвимость, помогающая подделать шифровку, перехватив всего лишь одну оригинальную шифровку: в отличие от соответствия хеша хешированным данным соответствие шифрованной версии хеша его открытой версии однозначно, что помогает если не вычислить, то подобрать ключ.

Comment: Асимметричные шифры хороши именно тем, что сложность вычисления ключа даже по известной шифровке известных открытых данных всё равно достаточно высока. Если же этим мог бы похвастаться симметричный шифр, то вычислительная сложность самого шифра ещё больше, так как шифруется не только хеш, а всё целиком. Поэтому чтоб не дырявить симметричный шифр, или открытую, или шифрованную версию хеша нельзя передавать с самими данными.